# Dynamically load Google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

If there was no internet connection at that moment - program can't execute remote script and create google object. Later i'm trying to reload google maps script like this:

```
if($.isEmptyObject(google)) {
    $.getScript('https://www.google.com/jsapi?sensor=true', function () {
        google.load("maps", "3");                       
    });             
}
```

I'm getting this kind of message: `Google Maps API server rejected your request. within the sensor parameters must be set to true or false.` Why?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
if($.isEmptyObject(google)) {
   $.getScript('https://www.google.com/jsapi', function () {
    google.load("maps", "3", {'other_params' : 'sensor=true' });                       
   });             
}
```

Comment: I think that I have to mention that I'm developing mobile application with phonegap and jquery mobile. Testing enviroment - Ripple Emulator. But now I'm getting blank white page after page loads.

Comment: No. It's Chrome app. So, basicly,  you can use chromes console.

Comment: IIRC a mobile app for phonegap should most of the time work as a regular web app. Can you try to run it in a browser which gives a more verbose debugging output, to see where the problem is coming from?

Comment: What does stand for IIRC? First time I hear it.

Comment: Oh it's acronym. :D Basicly you can output anything in Chrome console, even phonegap variables, I think. This kind soliution due to unknown reasons doesn't work. Maybe there is other one? :)

Comment: Ok... After some debugging approached conclusion that after success google maps API load jQuery Mobile somehow can't render page - blank page.